# SQLite matching on partial integer

Tags: python, regex, sqlite, conditional-statements

I have the following code:

```
sic_code = int(input("Filter by SIC code (1-4 digits)? Default is all: ")

# Connect to the database file
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
c = conn.cursor()

sql = ("SELECT Name "
       "FROM stock_data "
       "WHERE SIC_Code = {sc}".format(sc=sic_code))

# Run SQL query
c.execute(sql)
```

And here is how the SIC codes look in the database.

[image]

Ideally I'd like to match 7372 regardless of whether the user enters 7, 73, 737 or 7372. I've tried starting with a simple query matching on a 4 digit code but I can not get this to work. The query returns no rows. Without the SIC query, everything works.

Both the SIC column and the user input variable is specified as integer.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: try this  "SELECT Name "
       "FROM stock_data "
       "WHERE SIC_Code like "7%"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the above solutions worked for me. Instead, I exported the SQL data back to a pandas data frame and applied the regex there.

Thanks for all your help.

Regards,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `LIKE` in sqlite.

You use `%` and `_` with `LIKE` operator

You use `%` when you want to match some part of string eg.

`h%` will match with `hot` , `hell`...

`h_t` will match with `hut`,`hit`..

The `LIKE` works with `VARCHAR` not with `integer` so w.rt your question if you want to use `LIKE` to match `integer` values you have to store them as `VARCHAR` and then use

```
#input sic_code should be string
sic_code = input("Filter by SIC code (1-4 digits)? Default is all: ")
sic_code = sic_code + '%' #where SIC_code is stored as `VARCHAR`
SELECT Name FROM stock_data WHERE SIC_Code LIKE {sc}".format(sc=sic_code)
```

OR

You can use `CAST`

```
#input sic_code should be string
sic_code = input("Filter by SIC code (1-4 digits)? Default is all: ")
sic_code = sic_code + '%' #where SIC_code is stored as `integer`
SELECT Name FROM stock_data WHERE CAST(SIC_Code as TEXT) LIKE 
                                   {sc}".format(sc=sic_code)
```

*I haven't used `cast` but read the documentation.

Comment: I still have an issue where I can match the full 4 digits but I can't use the 3%, 35% etc. Error is: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Comment: check your syntax and check to be sure you are using like and % with `text` not `integer`

Comment: I believe I am using text, how would I verify?

Comment: @user3709511 using `text` as in, you are casting number to text or stored all numbers as text?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`regexp_match()` from SQLAlchemy 1.4](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html?highlight=match#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.regexp_match):

It works on Integer type columns as well.